# Web scraping to JSON/array

Tags: php

I am having trouble on web scraping. This is the link that i want to scrape:

```
https://www.indopremier.com/module/saham/include/data-brokersummary.php?code=BBCA&start=11/30/2020&end=11/30/2020&fd=all&board=RG
```

All I want is to take the data on B.lot & S.lot so i can SUM the data.
I managed to get the table information because the return data on that link is HTML, but I still confuse to put the data on array so that I can SUM.

```
<?php    
function tdrows($elements) {
   $str = "";
   foreach ($elements as $element) {
      $str .= $element->nodeValue ;
   }
   return $str;
}
    
function getdata() {
   $contents = file_get_contents('https://www.indopremier.com/module/saham/include/data-brokersummary.php?code=BBCA&start=11/30/2020&end=11/30/2020&fd=all&board=RG');
   $DOM = new DOMDocument;
   $DOM->loadHTML($contents);
   $items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('tr');
   foreach ($items as $node) {
      $list[] = tdrows($node->childNodes);
   }    
}
getdata();
?>
```

Comment: Try this plugin: https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48373292/4129620

Comment: thanks for the reply , really really helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Next code parse HTML and returns array of data. After this you can summarize data using regular array functions:

```
<?php
function tdrows($elements)
{
    $row_data = [];
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $value = $element->firstChild->nodeValue;
        if ($value) {
            $row_data[] = trim($value);
        }
    }

    return $row_data;
}

function getdata()
{
    $contents = file_get_contents(
        "https://www.indopremier.com/module/saham/include/data-brokersummary.php?code=BBCA&start=11/30/2020&end=11/30/2020&fd=all&board=RG"
    );
    $DOM = new DOMDocument();
    $DOM->loadHTML($contents);

    $items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName("tr");

    foreach ($items as $node) {
        $list[] = tdrows($node->childNodes);
    }

    return $list;
}

$result = getdata();

var_export($result);
```

[Share PHP code](https://phpize.online/?phpses=9a3b22d56892e3597d6df41d5eda8c10&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)